# time.clock() exact specification when running on the windows subsystem for linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, timing, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am attempting to time a certain select statement in python. The code I use to do this:

```
# Time the retrieval
start_time = time.clock()
rows = session.execute(cass_select_query)
mid_time = time.clock()
UDR_cass_df = rows._current_rows
end_time = time.clock()
print("Time to execute select: %s seconds", mid_time - start_time)
print("Time to put into dataframe: %s seconds", end_time - mid_time)
print("Total time: %s seconds", end_time - start_time)
```

I have read that "The method clock() returns the current processor time as a floating point number expressed in seconds on Unix," and also that "On Windows, this function returns wall-clock seconds elapsed since the first call to this function, as a floating point number, based on the Win32 function QueryPerformanceCounter."

I am using Ubuntu running on the Windows Subsystem for Linux. Which of these two timing rules apply?

Comment: Consider using `time.perf_counter` instead. (Actually, `time.clock` is deprecated now and will be removed in Python 3.8.)

Comment: @Ry- Thanks, I did not know about that. [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) is the documentation for the benefit of anyone who stumbles across this.